# Convert IEnvelope - ArcMapControl to X,Y screen coordinates

Tags: arcgis-10.0

Does anyone know how to do the following.

Say I have a map and I draw a rectangle over the state of Texas.  ArcMapControl.TrackRectangle returns the lat,lon of this.  However, what I'd like is to actually get the X,Y coords of the screen.  For instance if the map was 500 px wide and 450 tall I'd expect something like

top = 257
bottom = 242
left = 146
right = 167

Anyone know if there is an easy way to convert this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
activeView = mapControl.Map as IActiveView;
ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IScreenDisplay screenDisplay = activeView.ScreenDisplay;
ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IDisplayTransformation displayTransformation = screenDisplay.DisplayTransformation;
int x, y; 
displayTransformation.FromMapPoint(yourIPoint, out x, out y);
```

should pop out your x,y

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [IDisplayTransformation.FromMapPoint](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/FromMapPoint_Method/001w000000t2000000/) method, there is also a snippet that does this the other way around here that you can take a look at: [Convert Display Pixel to Map Units Snippet](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Convert_Display_Pixels_to_Map_Units_Snippet/0049000000n9000000/)